# LMGTFY.com ban?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blacklist

[Let Me Google That For You](http://lmgtfy.com) and [Let Me Bing That For You](http://lmbtfy.com) are both banned on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

I *thought* they were banned network-wide, but I just edited a link out of an answer here on Web Apps.

For those not in the know, they're both a rather snarky way to—via animation—show someone how trivial their question was to search for in one of the big search engines.

Now, I get annoyed at lazy question-askers, too, but considering web search is well within our bailiwick here and some people genuinely have trouble with it, it seems to me that the *last* thing we want to do is turn people away by passive-aggressively calling out their lack of search skills.

According to [Ban LMGTFY links across the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77377/ban-lmgtfy-links-across-the-stack-exchange-network) Jeff Atwood says that there's not (currently) a way to ban links network-wide, nor would he want to use such a "big stick" approach so each site needs to decide for themselves.

Should not these sites (and similar) be banned from being linked here?

Comment: we should.. I thought they were banned

Comment: Hmm. I could have sworn we'd discussed this already, but I can't find anything.

Comment: It's discussed _ad nauseum_ on [metase], but apparently not here.

Comment: Also of interest: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shortening-services

Comment: Another perspective: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93021/21960

Comment: What would a ban do to this question and answer? http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7930/automatic-search-tool-that-used-a-link-google-or-bing/7935#7935

Comment: That question should just be deleted since it's already closed for at least a month now

Comment: So...can somebody ping the dev team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, ok. It's banned.

Please clean up these:

- [How do I share a search query from Google?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21427/how-do-i-share-a-search-query-from-google/21962#21962)
- [Automatic search tool that used a link? Google or Bing](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7930/automatic-search-tool-that-used-a-link-google-or-bing/7935#7935)